# Entity Framework Core 5 does not seem to support Where/Include

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I read in the EF Core 5 release notes that include/where clauses like this are now supported.

```
 var results = context.Attendees
            .Include(a=>a.SessionPresenters.Where(b=>b.SessionId > 5000))
            .Where(c => c.Id == 1124)
```

However, when I look at the SQL generated, the 1124 is there but the > 5000 is ignored.  What am I not understanding?

Not that it matters, but here is the generated SQL

```
SELECT `a`.`Company`, `a`.`FacebookId`, `a`.`Id`, `a`.`LinkedInId`, `a`.`PrincipleJob`, `a`.`TwitterHandle`, `a`.`UserBio`, `a`.`UserBioShort`, `a`.`UserFirstName`, `a`.`UserLastName`, `a`.`UserWebsite`, `a0`.`AmazonImageSmall`, `a0`.`Authors`, `a0`.`BookPublishedDate`, `a0`.`BookTitle`, `a0`.`DetailPageUrl`, `a0`.`Id`, `t1`.`c`, `t1`.`AllowHtml`, `t1`.`c0`, `t1`.`c1`, `t1`.`Id`, `t1`.`UrlPostToken`, `t1`.`CodeCampYearId`, `t1`.`Id0`, `t1`.`LectureRoomsId`, `t1`.`MaxAttendance`, `t1`.`c2`, `t1`.`Description`, `t1`.`Id1`, `t1`.`SessionSequence`, `t1`.`SessionsMaterialUrl`, `t1`.`SessionTimesId`, `t1`.`Title`, `t1`.`Id2`, `t1`.`c3`, `t1`.`Id3`, `t1`.`TagName`, `t1`.`Id00`
    FROM `Attendees` AS `a`
             LEFT JOIN `AttendeesAmazonBook` AS `a0` ON `a`.`Id` = `a0`.`AttendeesId`
             LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT FALSE AS `c`, `s0`.`AllowHtml`, COALESCE(`s0`.`Approved`, FALSE) AS `c0`, FALSE AS `c1`, `c`.`Id`, `c`.`UrlPostToken`, `s0`.`CodeCampYearId`, `s0`.`Id` AS `Id0`, `s0`.`LectureRoomsId`, `s0`.`MaxAttendance`, `s1`.`Id` IS NULL AS `c2`, `s1`.`Description`, `s1`.`Id` AS `Id1`, `s0`.`SessionSequence`, `s0`.`SessionsMaterialUrl`, `s0`.`SessionTimesId`, `s0`.`Title`, `s`.`Id` AS `Id2`, `t0`.`c` AS `c3`, `t0`.`Id` AS `Id3`, `t0`.`TagName`, `t0`.`Id0` AS `Id00`, `s`.`AttendeeId`
        FROM `SessionPresenter` AS `s`
                 INNER JOIN `Sessions` AS `s0` ON `s`.`SessionId` = `s0`.`Id`
                 INNER JOIN `CodeCampYear` AS `c` ON `s0`.`CodeCampYearId` = `c`.`Id`
                 LEFT JOIN `SessionLevels` AS `s1` ON `s0`.`SessionLevel_id` = `s1`.`Id`
                 LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT FALSE AS `c`, `t`.`Id`, `t`.`TagName`, `s2`.`Id` AS `Id0`, `s2`.`SessionId`
            FROM `SessionTags` AS `s2`
                     INNER JOIN `Tags` AS `t` ON `s2`.`TagId` = `t`.`Id`
        ) AS `t0` ON `s0`.`Id` = `t0`.`SessionId`
    ) AS `t1` ON `a`.`Id` = `t1`.`AttendeeId`
    WHERE `a`.`Id` = 1124
    ORDER BY `a`.`Id`, `a0`.`Id`, `t1`.`Id2`, `t1`.`Id0`, `t1`.`Id`, `t1`.`Id1`, `t1`.`Id00`, `t1`.`Id3`
```

Models:

```
public partial class SessionPresenter
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
        public virtual Attendee Attendee { get; set; }
        public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Session
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ....
```

Suggestion that did not work:

```
var results = context.Attendees
            .Include(a => a.SessionPresenters.Where(b => b.SessionId > 5000))
            .Where(c => c.Id == 1124).AsNoTracking()
```

Comment: OK, so in the end it was an artifact, seeing the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because first attempt to solve this with OP's code failed, let's emulate the case otherwise. I used the app from this tutorial as a proof-of-concept:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0

LINQ query below and the involved data structures should be comparable with what's in the question:

- Course-to-Enrollment = one-to-many
- Enrollment-to-Student = many-to-one

  ```
  var results = _dbContext.Courses
     .Include(a => a.Enrollments.Where(b => b.StudentID > 1))
     .Where(c => c.CourseID == 1050)
     .ToList();
  ```

This generates the SQL below. `WHERE [e].[StudentID] > 1` proves that the filter is working.

```
    SELECT [c].[CourseID], [c].[Credits], [c].[Title], [t].[EnrollmentID], [t].[CourseID], [t].[Grade], [t].[StudentID]
    FROM [Course] AS [c]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [e].[EnrollmentID], [e].[CourseID], [e].[Grade], [e].[StudentID]
        FROM [Enrollment] AS [e]
        WHERE [e].[StudentID] > 1
    ) AS [t] ON [c].[CourseID] = [t].[CourseID]
    WHERE [c].[CourseID] = 1050
    ORDER BY [c].[CourseID], [t].[EnrollmentID]
```

Model classes

```
public class Course
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public enum Grade
{
    A, B, C, D, F
}

public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I just tried as you suggest with AsNoTracking and it did not help.  I don't understand what they mean by " re-create the DbContext when using Filtered Include"

Comment: I don't think I gave you the models so you didn't quite get the the relationships right. SessionPresenters has single Session and Presenter so I modified your suggestion and still no luck.  I updated my question to include what I tried as your suggestion and also am including the model for SessionPresenter

Comment: Just tried that, still no success.  I can workaround with some ugly multiple queries and addrange type work. Still love to know why I can't get this to work, but appreciate all your efforts.

Comment: I can send you the classes if that helps

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pkellner/73abb3b3e722c9676116fc7dc38baef8

Comment: this is somewhat embarrasing, but your answer works perfect.  I'm also learning/using AutoMapper at the same time and was looking at the results through `return results.ProjectTo<SpeakerDto>(_configuration).ToList();` which agressively gets all the sessions.  When I debug ToList() without the ProjectTo from automapper, the results show as you indicate.  Thanks for your help again

Comment: @PeterKellner: I'm glad to hear things are working now.  Been there myself, sometimes a simple POC is like magic. See you around. BR

Comment: Yeah, I often find that when I'm getting ready to post or ask a question, I make a small example and that solves my problem w/o posting.